# Exportar función JS a Angular6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Quiero ejecutar una función JS en Angular6 para ello estoy haciendo lo de agregar una interface de windows.d.ts con su correspondiente js pero me da error en el Angular.

En el index.html importo el js:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="moduleActive.js"></script>
```

El archivo .js tiene:

```
export function calc () {
    var prog = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    prog.run('Calc', 0, true);
}
```

Y está al nivel del index.html.

Después en la ruta de assets/ActiveX

He creado un fichero llamado moduleActive.d.ts

```
interface Window {
    calc: () => any;
  }
```

Finalmente en mi componente:

```
import { calc } from '../../../../assets/activeX/moduleActive';

.
.
.

 private ejecutar = function () {
     calc();
 }
```

El error es:

```
{
    "resource": "/d:/proyecto/src/app/core/components/main/main.component.ts",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2306",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "El archivo 'd:/proyecto/src/assets/activeX/moduleActive.d.ts' no es un módulo.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 4,
    "startColumn": 22,
    "endLineNumber": 4,
    "endColumn": 63
}
```

El error aparece en la línea del import del component.ts ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Has mezclado dos cosas:

- Los ficheros .d.ts son declaraciones que se "asumen" durante la compilación, no son módulos. Lo único que haces en tu caso es decir que existirá una función global `calc` que no recibe parámetros y puede devolver cualquier cosa (está en el objeto window).
- Has intentado añadir un fichero js a la aplicación poniéndolo directamente en el index con una etiqueta , pero no será considerado un módulo y además el compilador de typescript no sabe que existe y no puede ser importado en el resto del código.

Veo dos posibles soluciones:

1. Copiar ese código a un fichero TS y usarlo importándolo como cualquier otro fichero TS (lo más sencillo en este caso).
2. Mantenerlo como JS, lo que te obligará a...

   - Modificar el fichero .js para asegurarte de que la función está en window, olvidándote de módulos:

     ```
     window.calc = function () {
       var prog = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
       prog.run('Calc', 0, true);
     }
     ```
   - Asegurarte de que el fichero está accesible en tu aplicación, añadiéndolo a la carpeta `assets` (el builder de Angular no lo reconocerá como parte del código, por lo que no se añade automáticamente).
   - Importarlo con la URL correcta:

     ```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/moduleActive.js"></script>
     ```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puede estar diciéndote que el archivo no es un módulo porque en el nombre tiene la palabra "module". Pero yo en vez de meterlo en el index.html, que queda menos limpio en Angular, crearía un archivo .ts con la función que exportas y lo importaría donde lo quisiera usar. Así no debería de darte problemas en un principio.

Por ejemplo, creas una carpeta config y dentro el archivo "moduleActive.ts" con la función a exportar.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que tu archivo tiene la extension .d.ts por lo que TypeScript lo considera un archivo de "definicion" y no debe contener implementacion.

Renombra el archivo a `moduleActive.ts` y ya no deberia darte el error.

Igualmente si estas usando Angular 6 no necesitas importar el archivo en el HTML. Al hacer import en el archivo de tu clase deberia encontrar la ruta y usar las funciones exportadas.