# Pasar un body a un metodo get en httpCliente angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http-get, angular9

Al realizar en postman el consumo del ws agregando por metodo get un body, este retorna valores, pero al consumirlo desde angular no retorna nada, ya que no reconoce el body con metodo get.

Alguien sabe como se puede pasar un body a metodo GET o solo se debe usar en el POST?

```
const options = {
      headers: this.header,
      body: JSON.stringify({"impuestos": [1, 2]}),
      // tslint:disable-next-line: quotemark
      // tslint:disable-next-line: object-literal-shorthand
      params: new HttpParams().append('cliente', 1 + '')
    };

    console.log(options);
    return this.http.get<Servicios>(url, options).pipe(map(result => {
      return result;
    }));
```

Comment: consulta, si estás haciendo el `subscribe`? porque el `pipe` no ejecuta el request, este se ejecuta cuando haces `subscribe`

Answer (score 0):

El método httpClient de Angular no permite usar Get con Body, sin embargo, puedes pasar tu "body" a una cadena de texto y enviarla por get como una queryString sino puedes cambiar el verbo de la solicitud, aunque lo recomendable es usar post si necesitas usar body.

```
const options = {
      headers: this.header,
      // tslint:disable-next-line: quotemark
      // tslint:disable-next-line: object-literal-shorthand
      params: new HttpParams().append('cliente', 1 + '')
    };

    console.log(options);
    return this.http.get<Servicios>(url + '?impuestos=1,2', options).pipe(map(result => {
      return result;
    }));
```

Finalmente en tu servicio recoge el valor de impuestos y sus valores separados por comas o barras,etc y vuelve a transformarlo en un array.

También tienes otra opción, coge el postman y dale a ver el código en Javascript, lo copias y en tu Angular.ts llama a una función de un archivo.js que será el código que has copiado del postman.
[Exportar función JS a Angular6](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286880/exportar-funci%c3%b3n-js-a-angular6)

Incluso, puedes agregar los valores como una cabecera http al igual que haces con el 'cliente', no es una forma "limpia" y desde luego no es segura ya que te pueden leer las cabeceras, pero sino es información sensible y no puedes cambiar el servicio ...